# Is there a way to do a character/string restriction?

Tags: c++11, user-input, restriction

//The idea is, how to restrict the user to these specific symbols? p.s in the num_1/2 iput as: 10 is valid asd10 not valid

```
do
    {
        //Input
        cout << "Enter first the arithmatic operation (+, -, *, /, %) and then both operands: "; cin >> operation; cin >> num_1; cin>> num_2;
        if (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            continue;
        }

    } while (   (operation != '+' && operation != '-' && operation != '*' && operation != '/' && operation != '%' )
            && ((num_1 <= '0' || num_1 <= '9') || (num_1 >= 'A' && num_1 <= 'F'))
            && ((num_2 >= '0' && num_2 <= '9') || (num_2 >= 'A' && num_2 <= 'F'))   );
```

Comment: You cannot restrict the user from entering anything. The best you can do is check whether the input is valid. If it is, proceed to use it. If it is not, report the error and wait for the user to enter valid input.

Comment: @R Sahu Okay, how do I do that in this case? Because if you enter a invalid input I still does It once and I can't figure out how to check if is invalid to loop it

Answer (score 1):

The standard library gives you almost no control over this stuff.

It's an oldie, but readline is my still my goto for whenever I need a fancy input:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <readline/readline.h>

int snuff_key(int, int) { return 0; }

bool is_key_allowed(char c) {
    return (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
        || (c == '*')
        || (c == '/')
        || (c == '+')
        || (c == '-');
}

int main() {
  char* buf;

  rl_initialize();

  for (unsigned char c = 0; c < 128; c++) {
      if (!(is_key_allowed(c))) {
          rl_bind_key(c, snuff_key);
      }
  }

  if ((buf = readline("")) != nullptr) {
    printf("you typed: '%s'\n", buf);
    free(buf);   
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I bet this will be very confused when I enter `é` :)

Comment: @Quentin https://github.com/AmokHuginnsson/replxx is a similar library with unicode support, but I've never used it.

Comment: @parktomatomi i forgot to say, i need to find a way to do it without array's, pointers and so on, only with basic syntax. You don't have to write it, if you have an idea i will be happy